# How can System.out.printIn() accept integers?

Tags: java

So I started learning java several days ago and got a question. For the next expression:

```
String foo=123;
```

is not allowed. However, in `System.out.printIn()`, we can use something like:

```
int x=5;
System.out.println(x);
```

Since implicitly assigning a integer to a string is not allowed, why the expression above works? Anyone can give a detailed explanation? I'm also wondering when can we use this kind of  implicit thing and when we cannot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are so many overloaded methods of the [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) `System.out`:

```
println(boolean x)
println(char x)
println(int x)
println(long x)
println(float x)
println(double x)
println(char x[])
println(String x)
println(Object x)
```

Comment: What is (Object x)? A template of any kinds of objects?

Comment: @user1229490 It will use the `Object.toString()` method of whatever you pass to it.

Answer (score 14):

The reason you can call println with an integer is because the method is overloaded. Basically  there are more than one method called println and one of them accept an integer.

Take a look here: [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Comment: Why JDK 1.4.2 as reference? We are already in JDK 7 and 8 is soon to be released. Perhaps a reference to JDK 6 or 7 would be better.

Answer (score 3):

The static member `out` of the class `System` is a `PrintStream` which has a method with the signature `println(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the API for [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (`System.out` is a `PrintStream`). It has methods `println()`, `println(boolean)`, `println(char)`, `println(char[]`), `println(double)`, `println(float)`, `println(int)`, `println(long)`, `println(Object)` and `println(String)`. This is called [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) (scroll down to find the section on method overloading).

If you want to create a `String` from an integer literal, you can either put quotes around it  (`String s = "123";`) or use [`Integer.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29) (`String s = Integer.toString(123);`) or [`String.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) (`String s = String.valueOf(123);`).

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you mean't println not printin , java has a println function for each datatype, so you can call println on booleans, ints, strings, ect and it will select the right function.
of course you cannot assign an integer to a string variable because they are different types.