# int to String while String concatenation in java

Tags: java, string

When a java compiler sees a concatenation statement as below:

```
int x = 1234;
String y = "Some random String " + x;
```

or a print statement like this:

```
int x = 1234;
System.out.println(x);
```

How does it convert the **primitive** integer(int) to its **String** representation? I know if it was an **Integer** class, its toString() method would have been called. And i don't think here the concept of **auto-boxing** is taking place.

Comment: Your two examples are completely unrelated.

Comment: if thats the case, what happens in each scenario?

Comment: Here's some info on the first: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14782804/1553851

Comment: And here's some on the second: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10746174/1553851

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bytecode of

```
int i = 10;
System.out.println("" + i);
```

will look like this

```
GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
LDC ""
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ILOAD 1
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

As you can see new `StringBuilder` is created and `append(int)` method is invoked.

`System.out.println(10)` case even simpler. There is several overloaded method whit name `println` and one of them accept `int` as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Your two examples are not related.

**In the first example**

```
int x = 1234;
String y = "Some random String " + x;
```

Here basically following code is generated internally.

`new StringBuilder("Some random String ").append(x)`

**In the 2nd Example**

```
int x = 1234;
System.out.println(x);
```

There are so many overloaded methods of the PrintStream System.out:

```
println(boolean x)
println(char x)
println(int x)
println(long x)
println(float x)
println(double x)
println(char x[])
println(String x)
println(Object x)
```

here **println(int x)** is invoked

Answer (score 2):

String is a Class in Java. 
int is a primitive type.

You can't force cast a primitive type to an Object.

Operand "+" is a special operand, for example:

```
public class TestSimplePlus 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
      String s = "abc"; 
      String ss = "ok" + s + "xyz" + 5; 
      System.out.println(ss); 
    } 
}
```

let's take a look at the decompilation code:

```
package string; 
import java.io.PrintStream; 
public class TestSimplePlus 
{ 
public TestSimplePlus() 
    { 
//    0    0:aload_0          
//    1    1:invokespecial   #8   <Method void Object()> 
//    2    4:return           
    } 
public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
      String s = "abc"; 
//    0    0:ldc1            #16  <String "abc"> 
//    1    2:astore_1         
      String ss = (new StringBuilder("ok")).append(s).append("xyz").append(5).toString(); 
//    2    3:new             #18  <Class StringBuilder> 
//    3    6:dup              
//    4    7:ldc1            #20  <String "ok"> 
//    5    9:invokespecial   #22  <Method void StringBuilder(String)> 
//    6   12:aload_1          
//    7   13:invokevirtual   #25  <Method StringBuilder StringBuilder.append(String)> 
//    8   16:ldc1            #29  <String "xyz"> 
//    9   18:invokevirtual   #25  <Method StringBuilder StringBuilder.append(String)> 
//   10   21:iconst_5         
//   11   22:invokevirtual   #31  <Method StringBuilder StringBuilder.append(int)> 
//   12   25:invokevirtual   #34  <Method String StringBuilder.toString()> 
//   13   28:astore_2         
      System.out.println(ss); 
//   14   29:getstatic       #38  <Field PrintStream System.out> 
//   15   32:aload_2          
//   16   33:invokevirtual   #44  <Method void PrintStream.println(String)> 
//   17   36:return           
    } 
}
```

As we can see, "+" operand is to call StringBuilder.append() while at least one of the parameters is string

Hope you get it!